# ¿Cómo ordenar respuestas de POST dentro de un Foreach()?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Comunidad SO,

Como puedo ordenar mis resultados de la solicitud POST, para que se forme una tabla de imagenes y no queden por debajo del otro?

Donde recibo el resultado es un simple

`<div id="resultados_ajax"></div>`

La respuesta que envio en el archivo post es la siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../post/css/estilos.css">
    <script src="../post/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../post/js/script.js"></script>

                <div class="product-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo $imagen; ?>" style="width: 75%;" alt="">
                    <a ><?php echo $cliente; ?></a>
                    <a style="border-color: gray;"><?php echo $rubro; ?></a>
                    <a><?php echo $producto; ?></a>
                </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ordenar o posicionar? Si es lo segundo, podrías agregar en CSS `display:flex;` al contenedor. Te recomiendo leer [Conceptos básicos de Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

Comment: @Triby Seria posicionar, ya que el css si contiene el atributo `display:flex;`

Comment: Entonces, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega tu código HTML + CSS, creando un [ejemplo mínimo y reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no incluyes el código con el cual obtienes las imágenes (¿vienen de una base de datos? ¿de un folder con imágenes?), en general la forma más sencilla es:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach(): ?>    <-- Aqui recuperas las imágenes, for() o while()

        <div class="col-3">
            <!-- Aqui colocas la imágen -->
        </div>

    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

Usar "col-3" te coloca 4 imágenes por fila ya que la rejilla tiene 12 columnas. Puedes usar "col-4" (tres imagenes por fila), "col-2" (seis imágenes), etc. La rejilla se encarga de crear una la fila nueva cuando se llena la fila actual.